# Need expression value in ng-model?

Tags: angularjs

```html
<li><p><span class="voilet">Service Price :</span> ${{s_price}}</p></li>
```

How can i get {{s_price}} value in ng-model="variable". so that i could pass it to php form using AJAX.So, i need like this:

```html
<li ng-model="variable.{{s_price}}"><p><span class="voilet">Service Price :</span> ${{s_price}}</p></li>
```

Comment: Please post relevant ode and explain what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Yiipee got it A.J. Thank you so much.

Comment: `$scope.s_price` did the job?

Answer (score 0):

ng-model is for input,select, textarea (or custom form control), as the documentation says.
When you do use ngmodel you do not need to add the curly braces they are implicit.
if you are not using the lements above you should be using double brace and then you set the value on the scope object when you get back the results from your AJAX. Example: `scope.s_price = returned value;`
I recommend not using scope at all and instead using "Controller As" which will make the controller behave as the scope.